# Whats the correct way to download and save .xls file to Google cloud storage in Python GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

This is what I have in my code so far, but it doesn't work as a expected.

```
def create_file(self, filename):

    url = "google drive download url here"

    form_fields = 
    {
    "filename":"sample_file",
    "url":url
    }

    form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
    payload=form_data,
    method=urlfetch.POST,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

    self.response.write('Creating file %s\n' % filename)

    write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                        'w',
                        content_type='text/plain',
                        options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo',
                                 'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'},
                        retry_params=write_retry_params)
    gcs_file.write(results)
    gcs_file.close()
    self.tmp_filenames_to_clean_up.append(filename)
```

Comment: Explain what were you expecting, what are you getting, the more insight you can provide the better.

Comment: I want to save the .xls file into Google Cloud storage bucket. But it does not.

Comment: It seems OP wants to migrate a particular file from Google Drive to Google Cloud Storage.. Alternatively If you just want to upload files into GCS, create_upload_url is much easier https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions

Comment: @Hayato, exactly what am trying to do. I have followed the prescribtion here, but it says : TypeError: Expected str but got <class 'google.appengine.api.urlfetch._URLFetchResult'>.

Answer (score 2):

As https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open documents,

> **filename** (REQUIRED)
>       The file to open, in the format /bucket/object. For
>       example,/my_bucket/lyrics/southamerica/list5.txt

Your example `"filename":"sample_file"` is **not** in the required format `/bucket/object`; it's missing the bucket name and the delimiting slashes, so **where** (==to what bucket) should it be stored?!

You have a default bucket if you have activated the APIs in google cloud console -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate#Using_the_Default_GCS_Bucket -- and a free quota in that bucket, but you still need to tell `open` to **use** it, e.g

```
filepath = '/{}/{}'.format(defbuck, filename)
```

and pass `filepath` as the first argument of `open` (see the URL I've given wrt how to determine your default bucket's name).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use urlfetch result directly, Use StringIO instead.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
f = StringIO(result.content)
```

Then

```
gcs_file.write(f.read())
```